# iptables unban msn bot (IP RANGE)

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, fail2ban

I made a simple script for my apache2 web server to fight webscrapers. All works fine, but MSN bots are trigging fail2ban.
I made another script which I would like to run via cron, but need a help wit exact command to unban following IP ranges:

```
64.4.0.0-64.4.63.255    
65.52.0.0-65.55.255.255
131.253.21.0-131.253.47.255
157.54.0.0-157.60.255.255
207.46.0.0-207.46.255.255
207.68.128.0-207.68.207.255
```

I'm looking for something like this:
iptables -D INPUT -p all -s 157.54.0.0/16 -j DROP etc?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In old version of iptables IP address ranges are only valid in the nat table.
However newer version does support option that allows you to specify a range of IP addresses or ports for regular tables.

Try with this :

```
 iptables -D INPUT -p all -m iprange --src-range 64.4.0.0-64.4.63.255 -j DROP
```

For script you need put all unban IP range in a file & pass to while loop like:

```
   while read range
   do
     iptables -D INPUT -p all -m iprange --src-range $range -j DROP
   done < filename
```

Comment: This is the right answer to the programming portion of the question (how to script it).  The iptables command itself is completely wrong, since this adds new ban rules instead of removing rules (unbanning), but that's off topic here anyway.